# Gnome Extensions do not work at all after upgrading to 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell-extension

I just successfully upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04.1. On my first log in I was able to see the extensions in the top bar though they looked a little misaligned, however on subsequent log ins not a single extension works.

I've tried openweather, caffeine, multiclock etc nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

There's a main off switch under Gnome Tweak Tool > Extensions! Found this immediately after posting the question.[image]

Comment: Tweak tool was moved to Flathub. Link: https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.Extensions